# How does Nuxt.js auth use refresh tokens?

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, refresh-token, nuxt-auth

I have a Nuxt.js app with [Nuxt auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) module for authentication. My backend is in [Phoenix](https://www.phoenixframework.org/) with [Pow](https://powauth.com/) used to handle authentication. When I log in I get 2 tokens from my backend: access token and a refresh token. I understand that access tokens are meant to be short-lived while refresh tokens last longer and are used to extend a session. My Nuxt app has the following settings inside `nuxt.config.js` to read the 2 tokens:

```
auth: {
    ...
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'data.access_token',
          maxAge: 1800,
          type: '',
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'data.renewal_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
          type: '',
        },
        ...
      },
    },
```

I also have this middleware:

```
router: {
    middleware: ['auth'],
  },
```

So far I've only been able to test and verify that my frontend is successfully able to make use of the access token but I've got no idea whether it is using the refresh token and if so, then how. I'd really appreciate it if someone would be able to explain (1) how Nuxt auth uses the refresh tokens, (2) if I'm missing anything in my setup and (3) if there is any way to specifically test the refresh token usage.

Many thanks!

Comment: Recently, I spent weeks on this exact problem. There are a few blogs out there and it's possible to piece it all together, but in the end I arrived at the opinion that @nuxt/auth is really quite incomplete, at least for token auth. Maybe have a look at [vue-auth](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth). I'm also working on my own library for this, [vue-auth-jwt](https://github.com/johnckealy/vue-auth-jwt)

Comment: @JohnKealy hey thanks for the response. At least for now it seems that Nuxt auth is kind of working for me (not sure about the refresh part though) so I'd be reluctant to switch. Did you end up moving away from Nuxt auth? I've seen a few blog posts but none of them went into details about the refresh tokens

Comment: I got @nuxt/auth sort-of working. But for JWT it using localStorage (awful for security!) and there was a lot of custom code for middleware and redirects that I had to piece together just to make it work.  Honestly, it wasn't worth it. I know it's a PITA, but I recommend switching.